# 2 ways of assigning within a case statement in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

What is the difference between these 2 versions of the same code? Are they exactly equivalent? If yes, why this unnecessary confusing syntax?

```
let x : Int? = 42

if  case let .Some(value) = x{
    print("here's an x for ya \(value)")
}
```

Now, let's move the let into the parens:

```
if  case .Some(let value) = x{
    print("here's an x for ya \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other example:

```
enum E {
    case A(Int, Bool?, Int, Double)
}

let e = E.A(4, true, -2, 2.4)
```

Now you can do this:

```
if  case E.A(let n, .Some(let b), let m, let d) = e {

}
```

Or this:

```
if  case let E.A(n, .Some(b), m, d) = e {

}
```

I wouldn't want to type out all the `let`s, makes it confusing.